# Google Distance Matrix API "Error in Location"

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In the Google Distance Matrix API when calculating some driving/walking distances in Haiti, some of the coordinates that I provide (which were obtained from Geohack data) were not being identified by the distance matrix API and agives me a result that states “Error in Location”.

A few of the coordinates that are not identified by the Distance Matrix API are listed below.

Commune de Mont-Organisé    -71.783333  19.4
Commune de Carice   -71.833333  19.383333
Commune de Vallières    -71.917 19.433
Commune de Môle Saint Nicolas   -73.383333  19.8

The search returns an error that states, "Error in Location" when any of the above coordinates are listed as one of the start/end points. Why does the distance matrix API not identify some coordinates such as the above? Apart from attempting to use alternative coordinates is there another way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at those coordinates on a Google Map?

Comment: Yes I have. They appear without any problem on a Google Map

Comment: But they are in the middle of nowhere, not near any roads... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/h2hdzzbc/)

Comment: OK, I get it. I got these coordinates for cities from online sources (using GeoLocator data). Is there a better way to obtain the coordinates that are closer to roads?

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't need to "identify" a coordinate, a coordinate is a fixed value.

You can't assume that google is able to calculate a route from/to each location in the world.

Comment: Correct. These are some main cities in certain administrative divisions in Haiti. Therefore, I am not sure why I am unable to calculate driving/walking distance to/from these coordinate locations.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/h2hdzzbc/)

Comment: OK, I get it. I got these coordinates for cities from online sources (using GeoLocator data). Is there a better way to obtain the coordinates that are closer to roads?